# Divide by an odd number, 2-adically

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

Given \$a\$ and \$b\$, both odd \$n+1\$-bit integers, compute \$a/b\$ to a precision of \$n+1\$ bits in the 2-adic integers. That is, compute \$c\$ such that \$a = bc\, (\mathop{\rm mod} 2^{n+1})\$. \$n\$ should be your language's native integer size, or if native integers are bigints, take it as a parameter. If your language uses trits (and presumably is either Setun assembly, TriINTERCAL, or Malbolge), you may instead compute in the 3-adics, in which case \$a\$ and \$b\$ should be multiples of 3 plus 1.

Inputs should be \$(a-1)/2\$ and \$(b-1)/2\$ (trits: \$(x-1)/3\$).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes (per language) wins.

**Test cases:**

All test cases are truncatable; if the last \$n\$ bits match the inputs, the last \$n\$ bits of the outputs match.
Test cases (in hex, 32bit): (apologies for poor vinculum placement)

```
|  (a-1)/2  |  (b-1)/2  | (a/b-1)/2 |
|-----------+-----------+-----------|
| …00000000 | …00000001 | …55555555 | (1/3 = A̅B)
| …00000000 | …00000002 | …66666666 | (1/5 = C̅D)
| …00000001 | …00000002 | …33333333 | (3/5 = 6̅7)
| …00000000 | …00000003 | …DB6DB6DB | (1/7 = 6̅D̅B̅7)
| …FFFFFFFF | …00000003 | …24924924 | (-1/7 = 2̅4̅9̅)
| …4620BA27 | …1876DCBC | …48CAF903 | (random)
```

More test cases may be generated by multiplying random \$n+1\$-bit odd integers and taking the last \$n+1\$ bits of the result (then shifting right by 1).

A few test cases for ternary computers (nonary this time):

```
|  (a-1)/3  |  (b-1)/3  | (a/b-1)/3 |
|-----------+-----------+-----------|
| …00000000 | …00000002 | …51251251 | (1/7 = 3̅7̅6̅4)
| …23472148 | …12435871 | …65732854 | (random again)
```

Similarly, do the same with \$n+1\$-trit integers ending with a 1 trit.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for everyone to have tests in decimal? What is the expected output for `a=1, b=2, n=5`? I ask since two of the programs below output `19` but (*I believe*) \$b \times 19 (\mathop{\rm mod} 2^{n+1}) = 38 (\mathop{\rm mod} 64) = 38 \neq a\$ and I feel I have probably misunderstood your question (or *I am just wrong*).

Comment: ```b=2``` is obviously not an odd number, but I also agree that test-cases in decimal would be very welcome.

Comment: The issue with decimal test cases is that you can't truncate them as easily.

Comment: That random test case seems to have an error, since you've got the same value for both `a` and `c`?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 45 bytes

```
lambda a,b,n:(a-~a)*pow(b-~b,-1,2<<n)//2%2**n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZDfSsMwFMbxtk-RG1lSTrr1zzpX1ot2w5dQGalrsdCloa2IMIY3fQfBm4G4p-kL6KVPYpsEVJh-nJzwwfnlO-TlKB6bu5IfXrPw-u2-yejFOy3YNtkwxCABHmBG94yYonzACd0nQG1wFgtOxmPn3DFNrqHnrKxQgXKOSpFyPCFWlbJNkfO0xiQw0BoiiGEJ63DLBK6byupPLqCwalHkDR7tRoQYMvNWjuS8ARxd2cENxLIvh04A2z7IGsZ56JlFHxcR6hlIVD2E5ROQyZsTovY7fJzhHfp8Ok600E9nKzfV6h22xy4KUdS1MTH-Bh3lfC0FTntw2bWr36B9CnS1BtCVoN-1s_8SXeVWsS9LJc4UuOq3_cYvtU7hjjeXNeBU8U7Xel0771r9Y18)

Beginning with Python 3.8 the builtin `pow` can directly compute the modular inverse.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 32 bytes

```
f(a,b,n)=(2*a+1)/(2*b+1)%2^n++\2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNxXSNBJ1knTyNG01jLQStQ019YF0EpBWNYrL09aOMYKo21BQlJlXopGmYaBjqGNsqKkJEYYZAwA)

PARI/GP has a built-in p-adic type, but using the `%` operator is shorter.

Comment: There had to be a language with p-adics built in! No way I can do better in machine language.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```c
c;i;f(a,b){for(i=32;i;--i)c=a-b-2*b*c;return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDRasIwFAbg@z7FQRkkXbMm6WaFqDDdQ3ixm@TUaMBFidUJ4qsvs@hNMbc/3/l/OMjWiDGicsoSXRh6sbtA3LSSt4QxR3GqmWEyNzmqsGqPwQOqaxw6j9tjs4LJoW3c7m0zy5xv4Uc7TyhcMoB9uAWWDERZAZvBCx8vc/kqvv2gAEt4AYJS1XMfaSf7rko68eREWaf7qr5jacjEkyTvI8nnn7LuGIUSiBjXo6/FfHEPEmvn7sRoWRfAz51u0OC99fFMrrJr/EO71etDZPY36P3pHw)

Explanation: since \$(2b+1) (2c+1) = 2(2bc+b+c)+1\$ should end up equal to \$2a+1\$, we want to find a root of \$f(c) = 2bc+b+c-a\$.  We do so using Newton's method (as in the proof of Hensel's lemma), with the optimization that \$f'(c) = 2b+1 \equiv 1\pmod{2}\$, so it suffices to divide by 1 instead of by \$f'(c)\$.  So, we iterate to find a fixed point of \$c \mapsto c - \frac{f(c)}{1} = a-b-2bc\$.  (And since each iteration increases the number of correct binary digits by at least one, and we are working with 32-bit integers, then 32 iterations suffices.)

Note that it's interesting we do not need to initialize `c` to any particular starting value, since whatever the starting value is, we converge to the unique fixed point anyway.

Comment: (And trying my hand at manually translating it to x86 or x86_64 assembly, I got 19 bytes.)

Comment: Suggest `i--;)` instead of `i;--i)`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes

```c
f(a,b){return b?f(2*a*b+a+b,b*b+b<<1):a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDRSsMwFIbv8xTHiZCsmSRVOrGd4uYr7KrmImmbLTBTaTMplDx7TdaB7Nx88PHzn8OpVoeqmiaNJVVk7Bp37iyod43TpVyqRCaKqkBVFJy8ytxP98ZWp3PdQNG72rSPxzd0o05GRYeMdfAtjcW/rakJGhGEidI1vatk3/RlJspUwAZGNDLKPYWANILPYPQpYsVnsuE5S9n2I13vKbCBv6yzz912t/fg80u7bjvAcYUJpSwPuNtAFpgk5BKI89OFhMaLh@HLLiho/H@PESUTFG4EF4TM7dffsBz56Q8)

This uses the same method as my previous answer: apply \$a/b = ab/b^2\$ repeatedly until \$b=1\$, and then \$a/1=a\$.
Because \$(\mathbb{Z}/2^{33}\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\$ is a group of order \$2^{32}\$, this finishes after at most 32 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 opcode, 17 bytes

```
f:  sub edi, esi
    lea esi, [esi*2+1]
.a: inc ecx
    mov eax, ecx
    mul esi
    cmp eax, edi
    jnz .a
    xchg eax, ecx
    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8xT8MwEIVn3684VUxQIoc0UpUuLIWFqStC6OxeSpHdIttBhj8f7CSlucF@J7/7fI@8Z6vMz31L3vZ9e3aWAm5fnpAj6y6QMowVwLsP5EIDwp6/kf1xieWk90nLSeu4xJt6KClxg88dew9CkzHYptt@IdPVU9cgPk@MBTs3EfLrhaziQD6eAsq4lpBtzdW2mtnK2QKF9YfLbqmtRsJQAwYhO8Re4WK72y1AbPCxXFXQNsJ3agyUEoIwTGPU13TePtyVb1BQk2g6fzRbeOw6M479p0yknO8XCwIR9cdh5nYc@v4P)

## x86 opcode, 19 bytes

```
	xchg eax, edi
f:	lea ecx, [esi+1]
	lea eax, [esi+ecx]
	mul edi
	add eax, esi
	imul esi, ecx
	shl esi, 1
	jnz f-1
	ret
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes

```c
i;f(a,b){for(;a-b+--i*(~b-b););return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDRasIwFAbg@z7FQRES7VmT1FkhIqzuIXaxmyQ1LqBRYt0E6R592Yq7Keb25zv/D8fgzpgYnbRE5Zre7DEQqVDPEN2UfGvUVFIZtu0leHCyi2Pnzf7SbGF1bht3fPpYZ863cFDOEwq3DOAU/gJLRrwoAdcwYcu3qZjxdz/KwRKWA6dUDtxz2omhK5OOPzheVOm@cugwDZE/SDJfCFa/iKpnFAogfFktXjf15h4k1q79iVaiyoFde90Ybe6t/89kMuvij7F7tTtHtF9BnT5/AQ)

To make it comparable with the other a few

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 36 bytes

```
\(a,b){while((b*F)%%2^32-a)F=F+1;+F}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMH23PyU0pzEovjE-JTMssyU1JT4pMr4JNulpSVpuhY3VWI0EnWSNKvLMzJzUjU0krTcNFVVjeKMjXQTNd1s3bQNrbXdaqFqgxJtjczMzY0sLYyNTbmSbA2NjE1MzcwtLA0MuZJtsdsDNp0rmUtZITkjNTnbigtoRTLUClvbRIjJCxZAaAA) or [try the first few test-cases with `n` set to 15](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rdHPTsIwHAfweKRPMaMLreuAbtnwT3rxwNGTN4Sl7Qou2TrcBm4hPokXPPhQePPqU1iYCiSEROMuXX79_b6ftH1-yRbL90gVt-k1y-UNHU2VKKJUwRIr6uCQCti5vMCxLAqZ5QgnkQrCaBwVOSVoDhoJjdlkEle6_2e0Qpmc6bGElXDTbxMcp2NYWccV5tqiCukPNPJ6PpcPAYtTNYYl2o6asLyQMOyX_Wpgtk01TPr6b2CayiIDLNJY-zqs2UToCYAkDacxywKm0VkUyjDgVcDp67QY2efL0zvIMEfzx_solhDysx4yTWdIfJuhHu1Z5MrqPdW9b0cfjBLjxIDMJqjtGNToAE7dVYV_VwgQdL-4dsDmXqHAxEd6mDHGt-tQrMO-dlutlud5AOyjvR3a-T0thAgP0r7vr2h3hyb_Qevk7kHadd39p-7u0O4f6JAfpnVD_eSLRb1-Ag)

Input `a` and `b`, outputs `c` = `a/b`(modulo `2^32`).

Uses floating-point calculations to try each multiple of `b` until it finds the first one that equals `a` mod `2^32` (corresponding to R's integer size).  Note that this means that some inputs may be subject to floating-point rounding errors when `c*b` exceeds `2^53`.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 40 bytes

```
\(a,b){while((F=(F+b)%%2^32)-a)T=T+1;+T}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMH23PyU0pzEovjE-JTMssyU1JT4pMr4JNulpSVpuhY3NWI0EnWSNKvLMzJzUjU03Gw13LSTNFVVjeKMjTR1EzVDbEO0Da21Q2qh6oMSbY3MzM2NLC2MjU25kmwNjYxNTM3MLSwNDLmSbbHbBbaBK5lLWSE5IzU524pLI0krGWqHrW0ixOQFCyA0AA) or [try the first 2 test-cases with `n` set to 15](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZC7bsIwGIVn_BSpqghbcQROBepFXjowdspGIfINaslxaGJoIsSTdKFDH4qRN-gj1AVaqESH_out43POp9-vb-V6s9XWpcU9q9QDncytcLqwsMaWJlhSAbu3N9go51RZIZxrm0k91a6iBC1BK6eGzWam8f6faINKtfCxnNXw6I8JNsUUNtFFg7lnUYv8gFa1z1fqOWOmsFNYo9OqGaucgnJYD5tR2AntOB_62ygMbURGWBTG831Zu43QCoC8kHPDyox56EJLJTPeZJy-z90kvt7AR8gwR8uXJ20UhAMKBxFHYZiMSR_FDKU0jchdlK4O_g9GSXAZQBYT1EkCGnQBp70vhX8rCRD0PHSHAsevhQJ7ig8LIeSpDsWu7PDa9wPAOfDVLzD5P5gxxv8G9_zs916v9-cn)

This also uses floating-point calculations to successively increment by `b` until the total mod `2^32` equals `a`, but here they are limited to a maximum of `2^33`, which is easily within the range that is representable without loss-of-precision, so output for all inputs is exact.
It's *much* slower, though.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, since \$\frac{a}{b}\pmod{2^{n}}\$ isn't correct (which I can understand tbh, since the challenge is not too well-explained and could use integer/decimal test cases instead of hexadecimal). For example, based on the first test case (`| …00000000 | …00000001 | …55555555 |`, for inputs \$a=0,b=1,n=32\$, the result should be \$c=1431655765\$. [Here a slightly modified version of the top Python answer's TIO for the same test cases as integers.](https://tinyurl.com/3a5pt242)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - It's quite likely that I misunderstood, as I found it quite hard to follow the explanation, but as far as I can see ```a/b``` (mod ```2^(n+1)```) does seem to satisfy the first couple of test-cases - I've updated to include a link to show this.  Please do tell me if you still think I'm getting something wrong, though...

Comment: Hmm, with `n=15` it indeed seems to be correct in your TIO's. Maybe I misunderstood the challenge myself.. :/

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
€Mo%`^2→⁰*N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTGt981YQ4o0dtkx41btDy@///v7Hhf0MjYxNTM3MLSwPD/0Zm5uZGlhbGxqYA) or [try the first test-case with `n` set to 15](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq5Fsr21hrm1iYWep6WRo9qip8f@jpjW@@aoJcUaP2iY9atyg5ff//39D0//G/w0B)

Input is `n`, `b`, `a`; output is `c` = `a/b` (modulo `2^(n+1)`).

[One byte less](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTGt981YQ4o0eNG7T8/v//b2z039DI2MTUzNzC0sDwv5GZubmRpYWxsSkA) (remove the `→`) it it's acceptable to input the number of bits of the modulus (`n+1`) directly.  [4 bytes less](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTGt981UeNG7T8/v//b2JkaWJpZm5kafbf0MjYxNTM3MLSwPC/kZk5UMzC2NgUAA) if it's acceptable to input the modulus itself directly.

Comment: Wait, mod n+1? It should be mod \$2^{n+1}\$.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn - Sorry, typo in the explanation (fixed now): it is indeed mod ```2^(n+1)```.

Answer (score 1):

## ARM T32 machine code, 16 bytes

```
004a 3201 4350 1840 3201 4351 d1f8 4770
```

In assembly:

```
f:  lsls r2, r1, #1 @ Set r2 to b-1 ((b-1)/2 is in r1).
    adds r2, #1     @ r2 becomes b.
    muls r0, r2     @ r0 (which was (a-1)/2) becomes b(a-1)/2.
    adds r0, r1     @ r0 becomes b(a-1)/2 + (b-1)/2 = (ab-1)/2.
    adds r2, #1     @ r2 becomes b+1.
    muls r1, r2     @ r1 becomes (b+1)(b-1)/2 = (b²-1)/2.
    bne.n f         @ Jump back if that is nonzero.
    bx lr           @ Return.
```

This applies \$a/b = ab/b^2\$ repeatedly until \$b=1\$, and then \$a/1=a\$.
Because \$(\mathbb{Z}/2^{33}\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\$ is a group of order \$2^{32}\$, this finishes after at most 32 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

## Z80, 14 bytes (n=8)

Input is \$(a-1)/2\$ in `a`, \$(b-1)/2\$ in `c`; output is in `d`. Trashes `a`, `b`, `f`. (Well, everything trashes `f`.)

```
91 06 08 CB 38 1F 30 03
91 CB FA 10 F6 C9
```

Disassembled:

```
f:
    sub c       // 91       r = n - d
    ld b,8      // 06 08    do 8 times:
l:
    srl d       // CB 38    q >>= 1
    rra         // 1F       r >>= 1
    jr nc,ns    // 30 03    Was r even?
    sub c       // 91       N: r -= d
    set 7,d     // CB FA    N: q |= 1 << 7
ns:
    djnz l      // 10 F6    in any case: jump back first 7 times.
    ret         // C9       return
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＦＮ«⊞υ﹪θ²≧⁻×η﹪θ²θ≦⊘θ»Ｉ↨⮌υ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYuxDsIgFEXn8hWMjwQHdTKd1EWHmqbxB7BFIaHQ8nhdjN@OjS7V6eacnNsaFdugXM5nP1C6UH/TEUZRsiWbme8hclhKIfiTFTWhAZK8Ch25AKPkGzHXRaWGPaJ9@MY@TILKekLJr7bXCOYvl3z8ucBJuUl3X/1idbQ@wVFhgoNCDY2edJyXxOctypzXbMt2eTW5Nw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `a`, `b` and `n+1` as input and outputs `c=a/b`. Explanation: This is like long division in reverse; to get the `i+1`th bit you compute `c` to `i` bits and see whether you want to add a `0` or `1` bit to `c`. Rather than calculating `b*c` each time, `a` is reduced each time a `1` bit is added to `c`, and also a power of `2` is eliminated by dividing `a` by `2` each step.

```
ＮθＮηＦＮ«
```

Input `a`, `b` and `n+1` and repeat that many times.

```
⊞υ﹪θ²
```

Save the LSB of `a` into `c`.

```
≧⁻×η﹪θ²θ
```

If `a` was odd then subtract `b` from it.

```
≦⊘θ
```

Divide `a` by `2`.

```
»Ｉ↨⮌υ²
```

Convert `c` from binary.

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 44 bytes (11 instructions) (n = 64)

Call sequence: get \$a\$ in `$(X+1)`, \$b\$ in `$(X+2)`, `PUSHJ $X,div2ad`,
quotient is now in `$X`, and as a bonus `$(X+2)` is unchanged and `$(X+1)` contains a sort of remainder that can be used again starting an instruction later to get more bits.

Hexdump (jxd -T):

```
00000000: 26000001 e3020000 e3030001 76ff0003  &¡¡¢ẉ£¡¡ẉ¤¡¢v”¡¤
00000010: 3b030301 c00202ff 76ff0001 3f000001  ;¤¤¢Ċ££”v”¡¢?¡¡¢
00000020: 260000ff 5b03fffa f8030000           &¡¡”[¤”«ẏ¤¡¡
```

Dissassembled:

```
div2ad  SUBU $0,$0,$1   // r = a - b
        SET  $2,0       // q = 0
        SET  $3,1       // holds 2^i
0H      ZSOD $255,$0,$3 // loop: tmp = (r&1)? 2^i : 0
        SLU  $3,$3,1    // increment i
        OR   $2,$2,$255 // q |= tmp
        ZSOD $255,$0,$2 // tmp = (r&1)? b : 0
        SRU  $0,$0,1    // r >>= 1
        SUBU $0,$0,$255 // r -= tmp
        PBNZ $3,0B      // if(i <= 64) goto loop (that 1 bit got shifted off the high end)
        POP  3,0        // return q,r,b in that order
```